# Java: Cannot Cast to Custom Class

Tags: java, swing, casting, jbutton, classcastexception

I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe game in which a square in the grid is represented by a class called Square which I created. It extends JButton, but I added a boolean field called *pressable* which states whether or not the button can be pressed in-game. If the button already has a letter, then it cannot be pressed. I want to implement code in my actionPerformed() method that will check the *pressable* variable, and if *pressable* is false, it will not change the letter of the square. I am using the getSource() method on my ActionEvent to give me a reference to the square pressed. Therefore, I need to cast the Object to type Square so that I can access its *pressable* field. But when I do this, I get the following error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to tic.tac.toe.Square` This makes no sense to me. Before I needed each square to have a *pressable* field, I used a JButton, which worked just fine. But since Square inherits JButton, I would think that it would work as well. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.   please read these links ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask
http://sscce.org/ ) on how to post a question.  You will get a better outcome that way.  Hint( showing some code would be helpful).

http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

The JVM is telling you the truth: the object returned by `getSource()` **is** in fact a JButton and **is not** a Square object, despite your statements above. So the fact is, you are adding your ActionListener to a JButton and **not** to a Square object. You will need to inspect your code to see why this is so. If you need more of our help, you'll need to show this code.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> I looked into it and realized that my "Start" button was going through the same process, which is where the error came from.

Thank you for the update.

This suggests that you're using one ActionListener for all buttons, which you'll not want to do. Certainly all the tic-tac-toe buttons can use the same listener, but any others should use there own separate listener object, perhaps via an anonymous inner class.

Comment: I looked into it and realized that my "Start" button was going through the same process, which is where the error came from. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the JButton the first time it is clicked with .setEnabled(false) which would get around this issue. But I agree with HovercraftFullOfEels.